# SSRS - add textbox data to a chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, custom-code

I've created a report in SSRS. The report has a chart in where points are plotted on a scatter chart. My issue now is that we need a line of best fit, which is not directly supported by SSRS.

In order to work it out (as there are a lot of calculations involved to get it from the data we've got) I've had to use custom code. As such, the values are now contained in text boxes `(txtDate1, txtValue1, txtDate2, txtValue2)`.

Does anyone know how I'd be able to get these into my chart (so a point at the locations described in `[txtDate1][txtValue1]` and `[txtDate2][txtValue2]`)? Or would I have to go back to SQL to figure this out in there?

Comment: Instead of having your line of best fit values in textboxes, could you return them in a Dataset and just plot that on your chart?

Comment: Could do - in fact that was one of the avenues I was looking into. However, would that have to go back to SQL, or could I send the values from the report to a dataset (either through an expression or custom code)?